# how to not to enter the string jsf

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I want users to not enter the string just is entered number of phone, when i check validation at field phone number field.

```
<h:outputLabel value="" />                    
<h:inputText required="true" requiredMessage="Phone can't blank" class="form-control" id="phoneNumb" value="" title="">
</h:inputText>                            
<h:message for="phoneNumb" style="color: red;" />
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use f:convertNumber  tag with integer only attribute as true.

If you want to use Javascript, then you can write a function on onblur or onkeypress methods.

Comment: I did try it and was successful. Thanks Everyone :)